# Open CV Install Environment Variable

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I have just installed Open_CV and unpacked the self-extracting archive. Then I needed to set the environment variable.

I proceeded as follows:

Start > Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > New

At this stage I was prompted to enter the following:

Variable Name:

Variable Value:

For Variable Name I entered: OPENCV_DIR

And for Variable Value I entered: c:\xxx\build\x64\vc12

Where 'xxx' represents the path to where the build folder is located in my system.

My question is this and I am sorry as I know there is an easy answer I just don't know how to find out: How do I know the version of Visual Studio installed?

I downloaded from the visual studio webite but I don't know whether it is Visual Studio 13, 2015 RC,  Community etc...

(Please Note: Operating System: Windows 7, 64-bit)

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS version should be accessible from `VS menu > HELP > About Microsoft Visual Studio`:

[image]

---

PS: To make it work, e.g. for CMake, the environment variables should be:

- Variable Name: `OpenCV_DIR`
- Variable Value:　`c:\xxx\build`